# Renaming duplicate files while uploading uploads the file but gives WARNINGS

Tags: php, progress-bar, xdebug, file-rename

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO**

- I am uploading multiple files using the following PHP script and am
  trying to rename files having same names.
- Add a real time progress bar (radial).

**PROBLEMS**

- I am receiving errors yet my files are being uploaded with the new
  name.
- Have no idea how to go about having the progress bar to update in
  real time.

**PHP**

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['uploadfile'])){
    $total_files = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
    if( $total_files > 0){

        for($i=0; $i<$total_files; $i++) {

            $file_name = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp  = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $file_type = $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'][$i]; 

            $upload_Path = "storage/".$file_name;

            if($file_size > 8000000){
                echo ('Total upload size must be less than 8 MB.');
                die;
            }   

            if($file_tmp == ""){
                $errors = 'There is no file path.'; 
                die;    
            }
            else{
                if(!file_exists($upload_Path)){
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_Path);
                }
                else{
                    $name = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                    $ext  = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $new_name = $name.rand().'.'.$ext;

                    $new_Path = "storage/".$new_name;
                    rename ($file_tmp, $new_Path);
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $new_Path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**ERRORS**

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:\wamp\tmp\php35CF.tmp): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\uploader\mupld.php on
>   line 36
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\wamp\tmp\php35CF.tmp' to 'storage/instructions5361.txt' in
>   C:\wamp\www\uploader\mupld.php on line 36

Comment: Remove the `rename` line. `move_uploaded_file` is basically `rename` but with extra safety to ensure it's actually a file that was indeed uploaded.

Comment: Ok, that does remove the warnings but how to go about having a real time progress bar (radial)?

Comment: That's relatively advanced stuff. Have fun with that!

Comment: leaving alone radial, what about a simple progress bar? and how to update it?

Comment: Again, have fun with that :D The radial-ness is easy enough if you use a `<canvas>` or `<svg>`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol :D, well am having real fun for the past week but cant get to figure out how to update the radial bar. Anyway, just one more thing, why don't I get any response in my ajax success when I echo out errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115035/discussion-between-niet-the-dark-absol-and-ayan).